# How to have a tilted FNT font on Godot?

Tags: godot, fonts

Since FNT is a bitmap font I was thinking perhaps making the padding negative to the right and left side of the characters and rasterizing each glyph already skewed by an angle could make the font appear to be tilted. Does any one know whether FNT sports negative padding or whether Godot support some form of skewing that could accomplish that?

Please take a look at the image to see what I'm describing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A web search for "godot text padding" brings up the documentation for [BBCode in RichTextLabel](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/gui/bbcode_in_richtextlabel.html); among the text rendering option that can be adjusted, it mentions:

> `_process_custom_fx`
>  This is where the logic of each effect takes
> place and is called once per character during the draw phase of text
> rendering. This passes in a `CharFXTransform` object, which holds a
> few variables to control how the associated character is rendered: 
>  ...
>
> - `offset` is an offset position relative to where the given character should render under normal circumstances.

Comment: I'll give it try. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with any kind of font.

[image]

The image shows a shader written for a `CanvasItem` of type `Label`. To create the shader I followed the tutorial [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/your_first_shader/your_first_canvasitem_shader.html).